# How to filter based on either one of the columns

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a table consisting of two columns: `col1` and `col2`.
If `myValue` exist in either `col1` or `col2` it should be added to my queryset.

Using:

```
Table.objects.all().filter(col1=myValue).filter(col2=myValue)
```

Seems to just concatenate the filters and basically results in a empty queryset, as `myValue` cannot occur in both `col1` and `col2`. So how do i do a `OR` filtering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`django.db.models.Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) which can be combine using `|` (OR).

```
from django.db.models import Q

...

Table.objects.filter(Q(col1=myValue) | Q(col2=myValue))
```